# How to read JSON file from folder project ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I create a folder "js" inside Script folder and create a file json with array citys
and i try read this file on this folder and return a list to my select view.

```
{
  "cidade": [
    { "Nome": "Curitiba" },
    { "Nome": "São Paulo" },
    { "Nome": "Rio de Janeiro" },
    { "Nome": "Santa Catarina" },
    { "Nome": "Rio Grande do Sul" },
    { "Nome": "Acre" },
    { "Nome": "Goias" }
  ]
}
```

My class:

```
public class Cidade {
  public string Nome {
    get;
    set;
  }
}

public class Cidades {
  public IList < Cidade > cidades {
    get;
    set;
  }
}
```

And my action :

```
public class Cidade {
  public string Nome {
    get;
    set;
  }
}

public class Cidades {
  public IList < Cidade > cidades {
    get;
    set;
  }
}
```

**This is the error:** 
[image: asp.net error]

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Hi i add picture on post now, showing error

Comment: did you check if your json is being loaded correctly? it seems that is not....replace your json variable by the JSON that you have inside cidade.json. Probably it will works

Comment: `Server.MapPath` returns a path.  You need to read the file.

Comment: my json var return: "C:\\Users\\username\\source\\repos\\Exercicio 4\\Exercicio 4\\Scripts\\js\\cidade.json"

Comment: that's your problem...you're getting the path of you file, not reading it. Use `System.IO.ReadAllText` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-from-a-text-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will have the json file path not the contents of json file:

```
  var json = Server.MapPath("~/Scripts/js/cidade.json");
```

You should change it to following to read json contents:

```
  var json = System.IO.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Scripts/js/cidade.json"));
```

You are also missing an `s` in your json data. Your class has a property `IList<Cidade> cidades` while your json has the key as `cidad`

Comment: you also need to fix your json. Your `Cidades` is looking for `cidades` (with an **s**) while your json has the key `cidade`

Answer (score 0):

My final Code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get()
    {
        var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/cidade.json"));
        Cidade cidade = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cidade>(json);
        return View(cidade);

    }
```

My class:

```
    public class Cidades
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}

public class Cidade
{
    public List<Cidades> cidade { get; set; }
}
```